# Assign Different Pastes to Key Combinations

Tags: copy-paste

I have three different pastes to insert into a document.
Ctrl+v works for one of them.
But I need to assign a key combination for the other two pastes, **without** clearing the clipboard paste buffer.
The goal is to sequence:

ctrl+v: paste "sample text 1"

ctrl+0 paste "sample text 2"

ctrl+9 paste "sample text 3"

A clipboard manager doesn't help, because there would be too many keystrokes to load a the new "sample text." There are roughly 1000 inserts so setting up the keys makes sense. I'm on a Mac if it makes any difference, but I could switch to a different OS to get this done.

Comment: Not sure what the issue with clipboard managers is -- some do just what you ask, i.e., assign the latest clip to key-combo 1, the next newest to key-combo 2, etc. You might ask this question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which ones? As it is, I'd have to:1.open clipboard manager 2. Find text 3. paste text in document 3. open clipboard manager 4,. find new text 5. paste new text in document 6. open clipboard manager 7.find new new text 8 paste new new text in document....than repeat 1-8. That's 8000 separate actions, I'm trying to get it down to: ctrl +v, 9, 0; that is reduce 8 operations to three.